# Vue Component Event triggers but doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my code:

Tablecomponent:

```
<template>
     <rowcomponent @reloadTable="fetchData(pagination.current_page)" :item_data="item" :isDOMadd="false" :workflowoffer_id="workflowoffer_id"></rowcomponent >
</template

<script>
import rowcomponent from "./rowcomponent";

export default{
  methods :{
    fetchData(url){
      console.log('test');
    },
      components: {
            rowcomponent,
      },
  }
}
</script>
```

Rowcomponent:

```
<script>
    export default{
      methods :{
        safeData(){
         console.log('safe');
         this.$emit('reloadTable');
        }
      },

    }
    </script>
```

Console Output:

```
safe
```

The Vue Event gets triggered (vue-devtool) but it doesnt do anything

i Know it should work, but it doesnt. Has anyone some solutions or tips what it could be.

**UPDATE:** So i found the error, but i cant explain it ^^
I add this line in the Tablecomponent in `export default {...}`:

```
name: "TableComponent",
```

and now it works**

Comment: Is component 2 the rowcomponent? Why are you importing rowcomponent on Component 1, but declaring it on Component 2?

Comment: @Laerte I changed it in the question now its better

Comment: You should declare `components: { rowcomponent }` on Tablecomponent. And try to change `@reloadTable="fetchData(pagination.current_page)"` to `@reloadTable="fetchData()"`, and the method to `fetchData()` only

Comment: its already edited the component mistake. i also tried to call fetchData without parameter :(

Comment: Another thing, change `reloadTable` to `reload-table`. Uppercase may mess up emit. `this.$emit('reload-table')` and `@reload-table`

Comment: just tried, didn't work

Comment: The main idea of what you're doing is OK. Maybe it is some detail that is not working.

Comment: 6 Eyes are looking at the Code at the moment, and no one can explain, why it doesnt work, everything should be fine

Comment: Could you try this `@reloadTable="fetchData"` ?

Comment: @cafertayyar negative :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't share your row-component completely I made a working example. Can you please look at this and compare with yours ?

Parent component:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <rowcomponent @reloadTable="reloadTable" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import rowcomponent from "./components/rowcomponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    reloadTable () {
      console.log("test")
    }
  },
  components: {
    rowcomponent
  }
};
</script>
```

rowcomponent

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    click me to see the results
    <button @click="safeData"> click me </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "rowcomponent",
  methods :{
        safeData(){
         console.log('safe');
         this.$emit('reloadTable');
        }
      }
};
</script>
```

Output will be : safe and test